# GPG error when installing Epson Scanner driver

Tags: drivers, scanner, gnupg, epson

I am trying to install Image Scan! bundle from Epson for my GT-1500 scanner. When I run ./install.sh I get the error:

```
W: GPG error: https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 97203C7B3ADCA79D
E: The repository 'https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease' is not signed.
```

I looked into `--allow-unauthenticated` but doesn't seem to work for my case.

Comment: How is `downloads.plex.tv/repo/` is related to Epson scanner?

Comment: It is unrelated. You can either remove this repo, or fix the key.